# Wildcard Bounds if Class Generic Type is Already Bounded?

Tags: java, generics, types

Given:

```
class Foo {
    ...
}

class Bar<T extends Foo> {
    ...
}
```

Assuming I want to make a list of instances of `Bar`, with any generic type for `Bar` allowed, the type of that list could be one of two options:

```
List<Bar<?>>
List<Bar<? extends Foo>>
```

**1)** I'd assume that these lists can contain the exact same objects, namely instances of Bar of any generic type. Is this true?

**2)** Which type is preferred? Should I be more explicit and restate the bound on the generic type of `Bar` (second option), or just opt for a wildcard that is unbounded in the list, with the guarantee that instances of `Bar` can only be constructed with a certain bound on the generic type before being put into the list (first option)?

Comment: If this question is applicable to C# (not 100% sure, given that I've never tinkered with C#), someone notify me to add the tag, or edit the question to put the tag yourself.

Comment: C# generics and Java generics work completely differently. Better to never consider thinking about both at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I'd assume that these lists can contain the exact same objects, namely instances of Bar of any generic type. Is this true?

Both lists can only contain `Bar<T>` where `T` is either `Foo` or any of its children.

> 2) Which type is preferred?

Both are equivalent in this case.  However, reading code is more important than writing it; users might think "*Oh, it's an unbounded wildcard, so I can use any type.*", but they'd be wrong due to the bounded wildcard of `Bar`.  For that reason, the latter may be preferred in some cases, but at the end of the day, it's your call.